# Basic navigation in ContentControl

Tags: .net, wpf, prism

This drives me nuts. Im trying to do the most basic thing with regions. In my view I have a contentregion and two views. I want to show one on startup and the other one on button click

This is my module code

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
{ 
    var regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(Navigation.Regions.SearchHolderRegion, typeof(ActiveOrdersView)); //startup view for search 
}

public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ActiveOrdersView>("ActiveOrdersView");
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SearchAccountsView>("SearchAccountsView");
}
```

This is the view

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Seach holder"/>
    <Button Content="Open view" Command="{Binding OpenViewCommand}"/>
    <ContentControl   prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SearchHolderRegion" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class SearchHolderViewModel : BindableBase
{ 
    IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DelegateCommand OpenViewCommand { get; set; }

    public SearchHolderViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        OpenViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenViewCommandHandler);
    }

    private void OpenViewCommandHandler()
    {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("SearchHolderRegion", "SearchAccountsView"); 
    }
}
```

The first view is showing up ok. But when I click the button, I get to the handler and call RequestNavigate(...)  but in the GUI nothing changes, same view is visible. What Im I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
All involved views have `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`, all viewmodels derives from bindablebase. This is more or less a copy of the [Basic Navigation example on prisms github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/17-BasicRegionNavigation/)

Comment: Why do you register `ActiveOrdersView` for navigation _and_ put it in the region instantly? The linked example doesn't use `RegisterViewWithRegion`...

Comment: you mean in OnInitialized()? I saw some example as where to have your startup view. I havent noticed any difference in having it there compared to having it in the constructor of the VM. But Im new to wpf and prism. Just tested again to put it in constructor (if this is what you meant)

Comment: What I mean is: why do you not navigate to the initial view? There's a significant difference between registering a view with a region and registering a view for navigation.

Comment: If I just call _regionManager.RequestNavigate("SearchHolderRegion", "ActiveOrdersView"); in the constructor I dont see anything in GUI. Can you be a bit more specific? How would you do?

Comment: Regarding "This is more or less a copy..", what exactly did you change from the same code?

Comment: I found the example later, after I ddi my implementation, I didst start from it. I cant see any difference. Im starting to think its something else, for example, we are using Teleriks TabbedWindow, which made us do some adjustment in createshell() https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/knowledge-base/kb-radwindow-prismapplication-createshell

Comment: ... I take that back, Ive tried with good ol' Window and "normal" CreateShell(), no difference

Comment: @Cowborg which constructor are you talking about? Keep in mind that you cannot navigate from the shell's constructor because it is created before the region manager knows any regions.

Comment: The Viewmodel's ctor

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the optional "name" parameter in the `RegisterForNavigation` method calls. This will allow PRISM to make a default mapping between the view type and the unique identifier/key of the view.

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ActiveOrdersView>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SearchAccountsView>();
}
```

If you still want to provide a custom unique identifier/key as a method parameter, please you the `RegisterTypeForNavigation` method to override the default registration:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SearchAccountsView>("CustomKey");
}
```

See [the following page](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html) from the PRISM documentation for more details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats what I had in the beginning and that what I have now (again). does not make any difference  (for this problem)

Comment: Have you tried setting up a blank PRISM WPF project with just one module containing your functionality? Unfortunately, there is no additional information provided about your system setup (e.g. you mentioned Telerik framework in the comments). If you test the code provided in the question in a blank WPF project, both views are displayed correctly using the default PRISM registration: `RegisterForNavigation` method without the "CustomKey" parameter.